# Use internet from the router in an android tablet?

Tags: windows-7, networking, router, usb, android

My fried has an android tablet with an option in "Wireless&Networks" for "Ethernet", he would like to [connect the tab to the router to use internet in the tab](http://www.techulator.com/resources/7827-How-access-internet-using-USB-ethernet-port-Tablet.aspx), because the router doesn't have wireless and connecting an android phone/tab which has reverse teathering enabled by default to a pc with internet doesn't works, for which I have asked here for a [solution](https://superuser.com/questions/897311/android-reverse-usb-tethering), but no luck.

So come to the present problem, when we connect the tab to the router(by a cable which used to connect a printer to a usb port in pc) and using a usb to mini usb adapter to connect to the tab's usb port, the router recognises the usb connection, but the tab doesn't and we cant use internet in the tab.
Does anyone has a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have good news for you, this is something that the router is very likely not programmed to support, the vast majority of routers will simply be able to recognize that it is a printer or USB connected hard drive to share on the network.  The router will not have the drivers for routing internet packets to the USB port to send to your phone, and I am not aware of any router firmware that would even begin to support this.

Also, you appear to have spent a lot of time and effort trying to get this tablet connected to the internet without a wireless router.  I would strongly suggest that you see if you can just get a wireless router to save you the headache of trying to solve this otherwise incredibly difficult problem.

Comment: 1, that is a completely separate question, 2, Mokubai already answered your question in a comment, "that option is to give internet access (that your tablet has) to your PC via USB, not the other way around."

Service providers have setup software to make sharing your expensive wireless connection easy, so they can charge you more.  There hasn't been much work done to do what you are asking done, most people who want what you're doing just opt for wifi.

Comment: you were wrong at point 2, and I am sure that I can convince you about that.